# How to delete a exist symbolic link used by Sublime Text 2?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, path, sublimetext2

I used this at first, but I found I am using Sublime Text 3

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/bin
```

How do I delete it and use this instead:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/bin
```

Comment: Should not this be asking from the ubuntu community http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this:

```
sudo ln -fs /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/bin
```

There's an issue here: You don't know how to delete a soft-link you created, yet you're doing it as the super-user. Knowing how to create and delete files (which includes soft-links) is critical, and is an elementary skill for working with the command-line. Doing so as the system administrator without understanding what you're doing is asking for trouble.

Take some time to learn your OS; If you're serious about programming you're going to spend a lot of time there and will be manipulating a lot of files and their names.